# When I commit through git, it shows java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: java, android, git, github

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1100)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:112)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:571)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:512)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:426)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:398)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:805)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I push my code to GitHub through git in Android Studio, this error always appears! Could you help me to solve this problem? However, the error won't happen when I commit my code through git to my repository. Thanks for your help!
PS: Only one Android Studio is running on my computer